# Shifting into first gear not smooth

Tags: transmission, clutch, gear-oil

I have a problem with my 2005 Mazda Bounty, in that first gear has been difficult to shift into.

It used to be worse, but changing the gear oil, and clutch fluid has helped a bit.

Prior to replacing the fluids shifting into first used to be difficult at a standstill, and when the vehicle is moving. After replacing the fluids shifting into first is only a problem when the vehicle is moving. The slower I am going the easier it is to shift into first.

I will be avoiding shifting into first when moving to avoid causing further damage or wear.

Will it take some time for the fluids to circulate and take complete affect? Will doing nothing further cause more issues in the long term? How best to diagnose this?

My gearbox is a R15M-D. And a diagram looks like this,

[image]

```
Part #1 - 1st gear
Part #4 - 1st synchroniser ring
```

Looks like it does have synchromesh on first.

Comment: Does this only happen when the vehicle is stationary? If you try to shift into 2nd at a standstill, does the same thing happen? Shifting between gears at speed is no issue at all (up or down)?

Comment: Shifting into first is the only issue. Shifting into any other gear is fine. Shifting into first is only a problem when the vehicle is moving.

Comment: Is this a new problem, or something which has always been there? Also, how many miles are on the vehicle? I don't know if your Mazda's tranny has a synchro on first gear ... if so, I'd suggest it's going/gone out (or not playing well). Leaving this as a comment because I really don't know. My initial questions were geared (pun intended) towards seeing if there was an issue with the clutch not releasing fully, but it appears it does considering you can shift it easily while at a standstill.

Comment: I don't recall when this started. It has been there a long time I think. It has done 277 000 km (172000 miles). Synchro going out? Can I just ignore that and not shift into first when moving? It's not going to cause any further damage right?

Comment: By the way my vehicle has always prevented me changing into first if going too fast. I don't do that often of course, but recall my vehicle always doing preventing the shift.

Comment: If it's always been tough changing it into first, I'd suggest it doesn't have a synchro working while downshifting. Secondly, you'll have no issue doing exactly what you're suggesting: just don't downshift into first. You're not going to cause the tranny any issues.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look in the service manual and find out that gearbox type. Might be able to find some information from google. I saw this test too - https://www.jackstransmissions.com/pages/synchro-wear to double check that my clutch isn't dragging. That will ease my mind that the clutch is OK.